# xcode Google Auth swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have errors going on in my code is there a way to fix this?

```
didPressSend(button: UIButton!UIButton!, withMessageText: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!)
        print("didPressSend")
        print("\(text)")
        print(senderId)
        print(senderDisplayName)
        messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId!, displayName: senderDisplayName!, text: text!))
        print(messages)
    }
```

Thanks for anyone who helped. Im trying to get message text to send

Comment: Add 4 spaces before the code please

Answer (score 0):

Hello Try with writing below way.

```
func didPressSend(button: UIButton!, withMessageText: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!){
            print("didPressSend")
            print("\(withMessageText)")
            print(senderId)
            print(senderDisplayName)
            messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId!, displayName: senderDisplayName!, text: text!))
    }
```

Comment: nope same error   didPressSend(UIButton!, withMessageText: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!)
        print("didPressSend")
        print("\(text!)")
        print(senderId)
        print(senderDisplayName)
        messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderDisplayName, text: text!))
        print(messages)
    }

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'UIButton!.Type' (aka 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<UIButton>.Type') to expected argument type 'UIButton!'       Use of unresolved identifier 'text'     Use of unresolved identifier 'text'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your error is, I just correct as per my common sense:

```
func didPressSend(button: UIButton, text: String, senderId: String, senderDisplayName: String, date: Date) {
        print("didPressSend")
        print(text)
        print(senderId)
        print(senderDisplayName)
        messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderDisplayName, text: text))
        print(messages)
    }
```